# Set maximum selected per CheckBoxList in Repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, repeater, checkboxlist

I have a dynamic `CheckBoxList` inside a `Repeater`:

```cs
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt1_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hf1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chk1" runat="server" Width="100%" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatDirection="Horizontal></asp:CheckBoxList>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want the user to only choose/select 3 items. I tried many solutions, including this one:

```js
var limit = 10;
$(function () {
    $('[id*="chk1"]').on('change', function (evt) {
        if ($('[id*="chk1"]:checked').length > limit) {
            this.checked = false;
            alert('You can only choose ' + limit);
        }
    });
});
```

It does work, but if the `Repeater` has more than one `CheckBoxList` generated, the limit still counts if I select another item in a different `CheckBoxList`.

That means if I choose 8 items in `CheckBoxList` number one, then I can only choose 2 items in `CheckBoxList` number two, but the goal is to limit selected items to 10 on each `CheckBoxList`.

Any solution?

Comment: Show the generated html for 2 checkboxlists.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LUmeJ

the code would be so long, so i took a screenshot

Comment: Is the table a checkboxlist? Can you show the checkboxes?

Comment: Yes, the checkboxlists generated into tables. Sry i forgot to highlight it.

EDIT:
Check this out : https://imgur.com/a/iOhej

Comment: See my edited comment. And i think the checkboxes is within the <td> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$('[id*="chk1"]:checked')` to:

```
$(this).parent().closest('[id*=rpt1]').find('[id*="chk1"]:checked')
```

Tested against:

```html
<table id="MainContent_rpt1_chk1_0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="MainContent_rpt1_chk1_0_0_0" type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="MainContent_rpt1_chk1_0_1_0" type="checkbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="MainContent_rpt1_chk1_1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="MainContent_rpt1_chk1_0_0_0" type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="MainContent_rpt1_chk1_0_1_0" type="checkbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice work mate, this one works. I'll notify you again if something goes wrong, if you dont mind. Again, thanks.